# "svn log --search" command does not work with special characters

Tags: windows, svn, cmd, tortoisesvn

I work in Windows command prompt. TortoiseSVN installed in my PC. (I cannot install any software due to restrictions)

My target is to find list of files with specific comment.

If I have check-in comment like "bla bla" I could able to find the list of files with following command

```
svn log --search bla
```

But if I have check.in comment using some special characters like "DFT_V1.6" it does not find any file. I use it as in the following line

```
svn log --search DFT_V1.6
```

I do not get any output. I think it has some trouble to find the '_','.' and/or the numbers as well.

How can I fix it?

p.s: I could see somehow this info in the gui log window. But it is not convenient as I have to click every comment to see the affected file. Then I have to copy them. To many steps every time.

Comment: did you try to replace the underscore with a wildcard (e.g. "?")? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html

Comment: Hi royalTS, Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

I tried one day later with the same command. It worked.

I guess probably there was some delay propagating the comment.

So if you face such a problem try after some time.